# Have a matrix in Excel populate with data from a table?

Tags: excel, matrix, pivot

I've got a table with uncertainties that are ranked from 1 to 3 in probability and from -3 to 3 in criticality (-3 being a great possibility, 3 being critical threat).

Now I'd like to have these entries populated in a matrix, but I cant seem to find a good way to do this. The best method I found was using pivot-tables and then the new TEXTJOIN feature from Office 365, but we dont have that Office version at my work yet, so I'm kinda stuck.

The matrix I want looks like this when I manually populate it:

[image: Numbers in parenthesis is the position of uncertainty in previous period. The numbers themself is just the id# of the reference]

Any pointers on how I can make this work automatically?

Answer (score 0):

Asked this over on Reddit and got linked this [TEXTJOIN function for older Excel versions](https://un.reddit.com/r/excelevator/comments/5movbv/udf_textjoin_delimeter_ignore_blanks_valuerange/) which worked perfect. Just answering here for anyone that needs the same :)